# How to move label control within picturebox control

Tags: winforms

When I tried to move label control within picturebox control, My mouse pointer become "Unavailable"(Used to indicate a surface isn't a valid drop target).

In this case not any single event of picturebox are fire.

Is there is any other way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's still possible to move your label on top of your picturebox by going to *Properties* and changing the **Location** property.

[image]

If your label is no longer visible after this, it might be hidden behind the picturebox (lower z-index). To solve this, right-click on the picturebox and choose *Send to Back*.